# How can I have xterm execute my .login file when it opens?

Tags: x11

The title says it all.  I'm running Yosemite 10.10.3 with XQuartz 2.7.7.  Thanks for the help!
Expanded:  When a new terminal opens (e.g. terminal or item, which I mostly use) the file ~/.login is executed.  This sets up environment variables, etc, that I use.  When xterm opens it does not execute ~/.login, so I have to source it before beginning any work. So far so good.  Obviously, if i can get the .login file executed when the xterm opens I'd save a bit of time.  The problem is when I spawn a command to execute a shell command that is defined in the .login file.  This does not work if the .login file is not executed when the shell opens.  This is painful.  I've tried creating a .xinitrc file, but that does to seem to work 100%.  I need something better.  Of course, if I were a real unix person I'd probably know this, but...

I'm using tsch.  btw: if .login is the wrong file I'm happy to get the job done some other way that works.

Comment: Which shell program are you using, `bash`?

Comment: ~/.login is I think a c shell file - are you really using csh or tcsh? Also it will only be called if via login so might be the wrong file anyway

Answer (score 1):

From `man xterm`:

```
-ls This option indicates that the shell that is started in the xterm 
    window will be a login shell (i.e., the first character of argv[0] will be a dash, 
    indicating to the shell that it should read the user's .login or .profile).
```

From `man tcsh`:

```
A login shell begins by executing commands from the system files /etc/csh.cshrc
and /etc/csh.login. It then executes commands from files in the user's home directory:
first ~/.tcshrc (+) or, if ~/.tcshrc is not found, ~/.cshrc, then ~/.history (or the
value of the histfile shell variable), then ~/.login, and finally ~/.cshdirs (or the
value of the dirsfile shell variable) (+). The shell may read /etc/csh.login before 
instead of after /etc/csh.cshrc, and ~/.login before instead of after ~/.tcshrc or 
~/.cshrc and ~/.history, if so compiled; see the version shell variable. (+)

Non-login shells read only /etc/csh.cshrc and ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc on startup.
```

So in your case you can either make sure that `xterm` is called as `xterm -ls` (to have it act as a login shell) or rename `.login` to `.cshrc` (or `.tcshrc`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, which appeared after updating to the latest Mac OSX.
Opening a new terminal generated an error, namely 'If: Expression syntax', and .login was not executed.

Solution: delete the file /etc/csh.login, or inspect it to see if it contains an offending statement (in my case, a line executing a script associated with the mdsplus package).

Hope that helps

Comment: Deleting `/etc/csh.login` seems to be a rather bad idea, as it is the system-wide init file for `csh`. By default it only sets the path so if anything else is there it should be removed anyway (or moved to a release-independent file).